# Angular swap between 2 different class on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to build a toolbar with search functions in angular.
For example :
[image]

and this divisions are like:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="search">search field</div>
    <div class="otherElements">
      <div class="search-btn"><button>search</button></div>
      <div class="bookmark">bookmark_icon</div>
      <div class="otherIcons">other icons</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the `.search` will remain hidden. If i click on `search-btn` then `.search` will show up which will cover the whole toolbar. I can hide the div on button click by using [hidden] but the problem is `.search` doesn't cover the whole place.
Now it is something like :
[image]

if I click the search button :
[image]

what I want is :
[image]
I want the search bar cover the whole `.toolbar` if search button is pressed.

I have less knowledge of css

[Here is a minimal example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nzyexx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Angular ngIf instead of using css classes when trying to show or hide elements depending on some condition, like this:

```
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="search" *ngIf="!searchItem">search field</div>
<div class="otherElements" *ngIf="searchItem">
  <div class="search-btn"><button>search</button></div>
  <div class="bookmark">bookmark_icon</div>
  <div class="otherIcons">other icons</div>
</div>
```

In your example, you would also have to put a width 100% on the `.input` element to make it cover the whole site, like this:

```
input: { width: 100% }
```